# Tabular view of data from normalized SQL database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, normalization

I've tried creating a normalized database, but I'm having trouble displaying the data in a tabular format.

In my example below, the database is used to track numbers (in various, arbitrarily-named categories) by date. As an example, a user may track how many fruits and vegetables are delivered to his grocery store each day. The user defines the names of the fruit and vegetable categories, and how many categories are present. Here are the tables corresponding to this example:

A `tracker` table:

```
 id |      name       
----+---------------------
  1 | Grocery deliveries 
  2 | Sports cars
```

An `entries` table:

```
 id |      datetime       | tracker_id 
----+---------------------+------------
  1 | 2013-10-01 00:00:00 |          1
  2 | 2013-10-02 00:00:00 |          1
  3 | 2013-10-03 00:00:00 |          1
```

A `values` table:

```
 id | number | entry_id | category_id 
----+--------+----------+-------------
  1 |   10.0 |        1 |          1
  3 |   20.0 |        1 |          2
  5 |   21.0 |        1 |          3
  7 |   18.0 |        2 |          2
  8 |    4.0 |        3 |          1
  9 |    9.0 |        3 |          2
```

And a `category` table:

```
 id |     name        | tracker_id 
----+-----------------+------------
  1 | Tomatoes        |          1
  2 | Carrots         |          1
  3 | Brussel sprouts |          1
  4 | Ferraris        |          2
```

I'd like to print out a table for tracker 1, with each row corresponding to a date (no repeated dates). The columns would be: date, category 1 (Tomatoes), category 2 (Carrots), category 3 (Brussel sprouts). If there was no value for a given category on a given date, it would be empty or show as null. So, ideally, it would look something like this:

```
 datetime            | Tomatoes | Carrots | Brussel sprouts
---------------------+----------+---------+-----------------
 2013-10-01 00:00:00 | 10.0     | 20.0    | 21.0
 2013-10-02 00:00:00 | Null     | 18.0    | Null
 2013-10-03 00:00:00 | 4.0      | Null    | 9.0
```

I'm not sure how to do this, or if there's a better way to store this data. Any suggestions?

It was easy to display the data when the `entries` and `values` were represented by a single table (entries were rows, values were columns). But in that case, the maximum number of categories was limited by the number of columns in my table. I prefer how the normalized approach allows each "tracker" to represent an arbitrary number of categories.

Comment: If you want to do that in a query and you don't know the possible columns in advance, you need to create a pivot query, which is not possible with standard SQL, but supported by some DBMS. Do you know it is just the three columns (Tomatoes, Carrots, Brussel sprouts)?

Comment: What is your exact RDBMS (SQL *Flavor*)? Do you know the number of columns and their headers at design time?

Comment: @FabianBüttner no, I'd like each "tracker" to have a different set of categories defined by the user. The names and number of categories would be defined by the user.

Comment: @PM77-1 PostgreSQL. No, I don't know the number of columns or their headers. I've considered fixing the number of columns to some max (say 10... who would ever need more than 10 categories??). But allowing an arbitrary number of categories per tracker would be ideal.

Comment: Have a look at [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) functions.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks, I tried devising a solution using crosstab below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would define your tables:

```
deliveries
    id          unsigned int(P)
    good_id     unsigned int(F goods.id)
    qwhen       datetime
    quantity    double

+----+---------+------------+----------+
| id | good_id | qwhen      | quantity |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-10-01 |     10.0 |
|  2 |       2 | 2013-10-01 |     20.0 |
|  3 |       3 | 2013-10-01 |     21.0 |
|  4 |       2 | 2013-10-02 |     18.0 |
|  5 |       1 | 2013-10-03 |      4.0 |
|  6 |       2 | 2013-10-03 |      9.0 |
|  7 |       1 | 2013-10-01 |      3.0 |
| .. | ....... | ...........| ........ |
+----+---------+------------+----------+

good_types
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    name                varchar(50)

+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Groceries   |
|  2 | Sports cars |
+----+-------------+

goods
    id              unsigned int(P)
    good_type_id    unsigned int(F good_types.id)
    name            varchar(50)

+----+--------------+-----------------+
| id | good_type_id | name            |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
|  1 |            1 | Tomatoes        |
|  2 |            1 | Carrots         |
|  3 |            1 | Brussel Sprouts |
|  4 |            2 | Ferraris        |
| .. | ............ | ............... |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
```

And here's the SQL to get the column names:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM goods
WHERE good_type_id = 1

+----+-----------------+
| id | name            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Tomatoes        |
|  2 | Carrots         |
|  3 | Brussel Sprouts |
+----+-----------------+
```

And here's the SQL to get the data to show in the table:

```
SELECT qwhen, good_id, sum(quantity) AS total
FROM deliveries d
LEFT JOIN goods g ON d.good_id = g.id
WHERE good_type_id = 1
GROUP BY qwhen, good_id

+------------+---------+-------+
| qwhen      | good_id | total |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2013-10-01 |       1 |    13 |
| 2013-10-01 |       2 |    20 |
| 2013-10-01 |       3 |    21 |
| 2013-10-02 |       2 |    18 |
| 2013-10-03 |       1 |     4 |
| 2013-10-03 |       2 |     9 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

So then you'll use PHP, Java or whatever your high-level language is to loop through the two query results to display the data. Below is PHP code to display the data and below the PHP code is an image showing you what is displayed.

```
// Get the column headers
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM goods WHERE good_type_id = 1';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

// Start our table.
echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0"><thead>';

// Print out the headers.
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<th>'. $row['name'] .'</th>';
    $columns[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead><tbody>';

// Get the data.
$sql = 'SELECT qwhen, good_id, sum(quantity) AS total FROM deliveries d LEFT JOIN goods g ON d.good_id = g.id WHERE good_type_id = 1 GROUP BY qwhen, good_id';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

// Manipulate the data into an array.
$save_date = NULL;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    if ($save_date !== $row['qwhen']){
        $save_date = $row['qwhen'];
        $data[$row['qwhen']] = array();
    }
    $data[$row['qwhen']][$row['good_id']] = $row['total'];
}

// Print out the table data.
foreach ($data AS $date => $cell){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $date .'</td>';
    foreach ($columns AS $id => $name){
        echo '<td align="right">';
        if (isset($cell[$id])){
            echo $cell[$id];
        }else{
            echo '&nbsp;';
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

// End our table.
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pX5IIum.jpg]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP, but can you confirm this resultant table will give one row per date? I'm not seeing how that will happen.

Comment: @LorenzForvang - I added an image that shows what the resulting HTML table looks like and the PHP code that creates the HTML table. You'll see it has one rate per date and the totals of each `good` are calculated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an alternative using PostgreSQL's `crosstab` function, as suggested by @PM77-1.

Specifically, I'm using the [`crosstab(text source_sql, text category_sql)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tablefunc.html#AEN150863) form of the function, as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  crosstab('SELECT e.datetime, v.category_id, v.number 
            FROM entries e, values v 
            WHERE v.entry_id = e.id AND e.tracker_id = 1 ORDER BY 1, 2', 
           'SELECT id FROM categories WHERE tracker_id = 1 ORDER BY 1')
  AS (row_name timestamp without time zone,
      tomatoes numeric,
      carrots numeric,
      brussel_sprouts numeric);
```

With this approach, the `AS (...)` term must be unique for each tracker, since the number of categories and their names may be different for each tracker. In my case, I'm executing the query using Python and the psycopg2 module, so it's straightforward to generate the query dynamically. For instance,

```py
# Retrieve the category names for the current tracker
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM categories WHERE tracker_id = " + 
            str(tracker_id) + ";")
categories = cur.fetchall()
category_count = len(categories)

# Generate category string
cat_str = '';
for n in range(category_count):
    cat_str = cat_str + ", cat_" + str(n) + " numeric"

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM crosstab("
            "'SELECT e.datetime, v.category_id, v.number FROM entries e, values v"
            " WHERE v.entry_id = e.id"
            " AND e.tracker_id = " + str(tracker_id) +
            " ORDER BY 1, 2;',"
            " 'SELECT id FROM categories WHERE tracker_id =" + 
            str(tracker_id) + "')"
            " AS (row_name timestamp without time zone" + cat_str + ");")

results = cur.fetchall()
```

The result has generic column names `cat_0, cat_1, etc.` instead of `tomatoes, carrots, etc.`. However, I pass both `categories` and `results` to an HTML template to render the table with the correct headings.